# Refresh SSAS post ETL Process job

Tags: ssas, azure-data-factory

Based on MSFT documentation, there is no direct connector to SSAS and so is there any way via which we can process SSAS from ADF ?
As we have our SSAS but our source is Azure SQL which gets populated via ADF

Comment: Is this SSAS Tabular or SSAS Multidimensional? Is it SSAS in a VM or AAS (Azure Analysis Services)? I recall having this issue and I'm trying to remember how I solved it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no direct connector to SSAS in ADF but you can leverage the concept of linked server across SSAS and database and connect to database to process the cube.
my below blog explains in detail w.r.t same:
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/15/refresh-ssas-tabular-model-from-azure-data-factory/

Answer (score -1):

we have SSAS tabular model in Azure + Data factory and we have solved this by having an azure function that triggers SSAS process with TMSL script.

Take a look at this:
[Process SSAS from ADF](https://jorgklein.com/2018/01/30/process-azure-analysis-services-objects-from-azure-data-factory-v2-using-a-logic-app/)

Comment: Hey Ruben, The one which you shared is for Azure analysis services and not SSAS.
SSAS doesnt have REST API based on my knowledge.